# Criterion for a monomorphism to be an immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A map $f$ between schemes is a monomorphism if and only if $f$ is radicial and formally unramified.

In particular if $f$ is locally of finite type, $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if $f$ is radicial and unramified, cf for instance https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06ND

We deduce that an open immersion is the same as a flat monomorphism locally of finite presentation, and that a closed immersion is the same as a proper monomorphism. This can be seen as a generalisation of the criteria that a projective map is a closed immersion if it is injective on points (=radicial) and injective on tangent vectors (=unramified).

I am wondering if there is some criteria for a monomorphism locally of finite presentation to be an immersion.

The standard example of a monomorphism which is not an immersion comes from the normalisation map of a nodal curve $C$: if $\tilde{C}$ is the blow up of $C$, and we remove one of the two points $P_1, P_2$ above the singular node in $C$, then $\tilde{C} \setminus {P_1} \to C$ is a monomorphism which is not an immersion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer in EGA IV.15.7.6 where it is stated that the following are equivalent, for $f: X \to Y$ a morphism of finite type between locally noetherian schemes:

- $f = h \circ g$ where $g$ is proper and $h$ an immersion
- $f(X)$ is locally closed as a topological space, and if $Z$ is the open subscheme corresponding to $f(X)$ in its schematic closure, then $f: X \to Z$ is proper
- $f$ is proper at every point $y \in f(X)$
- the local valuative criteria hold at $f(X)$ (cf the statement for more details)

Now if $f$ is furthermore a monomorphism, then in the decomposition $f=h \circ g$ as above then $g$ is a proper monomorphism, so is a closed immersion, hence $f$ is an immersion. So the condition I was looking for is: a monomorphism is an immersion iff it is proper at every point in its image.